# How to update button colors continually [JAVA SWING]

Tags: java, swing

I made a class which takes as parameters 2 dimentions ( n,m ) and a matrix ( mat ). This class makes a JFrame,fills it with buttons colored white(for 1's) or black( for 0's).

The issue is, the matrix being sent is continually changing and i want the button colors to update. If i set the `mainframe game = new mainframe(n,m,mat)` inside the loop im changing the matrix in,it continually spawns JFrame windows.

I read some stuff on this site that using repaint() or revalidate() could do something like this. I tried putting it in various segments of code but had no luck with it.

The main class is just a loop which calls "mainframe" and updates a matrix in a loop. Here is the class which makes the actual GUI work:

```
package game;
import java.awt.Color;

public class mainframe extends Jframe {

     public mainframe(int n,int m,int mat[][]){
          JButton[] buttons = new JButton[n*m];
          setSize(600,400);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setVisible(true);
          setLayout(new GridLayout(n,m));

          for(int i = 0; i<n*m;i++) {
          buttons[i] = new JButton();
          }

          int counter = 0;
          for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
             for(int k=0;k<m;k++){
                 if(mat[j][k]==0){
                      buttons[counter].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                 }
                 add(buttons[counter]);
                 counter++;
               }
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: I can probably assist but you need to include more code.  Preferably a [mcve].  And you should not be extending JFrame.  Just use an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `setVisible(true);` or `revalidate();` after you added your components. Better work with the [frame content pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane-java.awt.Container-).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(600, 400);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 5; i < 10; ++i) {
            jFrame.setContentPane(createPanel(i, i, new int[i][i]));
            jFrame.revalidate();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public static JPanel createPanel(int n, int m, int[][] mat) {
        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[n * m];
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

        jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(n, m));

        for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                int index = k + k * j;

                if (mat[j][k] == 0) {
                    buttons[index].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                jPanel.add(buttons[index]);
            }
        }

        return jPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify on how that helps the issue? Im getting the same results.

Comment: @user569685 I've edited the post and posted the full code. I hope that I understood your requirement.